# nvme SSD not found by ubuntu

Tags: boot, ssd

I have a dell laptop with a HDD (Ubuntu 20.04 installed on HDD) and an additional SSD (Kingston nvme). Recently I had an unexpected freeze and reboot. Ever since then when I boot my laptop the following happens:

- The ubuntu load screen stays on for an unusually long amount of time (8-10 minutes)
- I am then shown a screen saying I am in 'emergency mode' and prompted to press control-d to continue
- After an additional 2 minute load I reach the login screen.

However once I log in:

- The SSD is no longer mounted
- Running `lsblk` or `df` does not show the SSD at all
- GParted cannot find the SSD as well

The only place where I was able to detect the SSD is in the boot menu:
[link to photo of boot menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XmF7.jpg)

I would appreciate any help in recovering the disk or data on it.

PS: the disk itself is quite new (I've been using it for about two weeks)

Comment: Did anything change in the bios after the freeze/reboot? EFI boot vs legacy? In my experience this can happen and will make some drives unavailable